# How to create labeling data?

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing

I have hundreds of images, each image is one of eight different types of blood cells. The names of the images indicate what type of blood cell it is.

I am having trouble getting started with image pre-processing for building a CNN. My current approach is to first read in my images, and convert to one hot encoding. Then, for each image have another vector of size 1x8. Since I have 8 images, I'll assign each image to a number and work from there. Is the right way to proceed or should this be done differently?

Comment: Why one hot encoding of image itself? I see no point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an example for cifar-10 data. It is a dataset with 10 categories like your image dataset has 8 classes.
[image]

Each image in cifar-10 is of size 32x32 and 3 channels of colour. The labels can be set using one hot encoding or without.

If one hot, then you are right the labels(i.e y) will be of size (num_samples, classes). That is if you have 1000 images for each category(or class) and have 8 classes, your label size(y) will be (8000, 8) and your image_size(x) will be (8000, 3, w,h) where w,h is width and height of the image(assuming colour image, hence the 3)

Without one-hot labels(y) would be of size (num_samples,). That is each entry in label array would be a number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, in one hot encoding, isn't each image supposed to be a 2d image instead of 3d. In other words, isn't each image vector dimension supposed to be 1x(32*32), where each value is some number between [0,255]?

Comment: One hot encoding is a way of giving a label to the image. It is not part of the image. example - if you have two classes (say car and bike), with one-hot-encoding your labels can be 10 for car and 01 for bike. Without one-hot-encoding it can be 0 for car and 1 for bike. Ultimately it is a way of representation. So basically, x_train will be array of images, and y_train will be array of labels. Hope this helps